# Removing (grouping by) arrays which are subsets of the biggest array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, aggregate, subset

I have a dataset which looks like this:

```
| path              |
|-----------------  |
| {16,13}           |
| {16,85}           |
| {16,85,1}         |
| {16,85,2}         |
| {16,85,15}        |
| {16,85,80}        |
| {16,85,80,1}      |
| {16,85,80,63}     |
| {16,85,80,63,1}   |
```

The path column represents a kind of hierarchical path through a graph, from some node to a another node. I'm trying to collapse each path down into the longest paths from root to leaf nodes - it should be noted that the order of the elements is important (`{1, 2, 3}` != `{3, 2, 1}`).

As an example:

- The path `{16, 13}` is the longest path containing both 16 and 13 *in that order*, so it stays.
- The path `{16, 85}` is not the longest, as there is a longer path containing those elements *in that order*, namely `{16, 85, 2}`. Therefore the row with `{16, 85}` should be discarded from the result set, and `{16, 85, 2}` should be kept as it happens to be the longest.
- Etc. with every other row

So the resulting set looks like:

```
| path              |
|-----------------  |
| {16,13}           |
| {16,85,1}         |
| {16,85,2}         |
| {16,85,15}        |
| {16,85,80,1}      |
| {16,85,80,63,1}   |
```

I'm not sure even where to start with this, everything I've tried has failed.

I've found that there is something called the array contains operator `@>`, but don't really know how the apply it.

Is there a reasonable query for doing this? Any help would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want the "not contains" operator.  So, you can do:

```
select p.*
from paths p
where not exists (select 1
                  from paths p2
                  where p2.path @> p.path and p2.path <> p.path
                 );
```

I'm not promising that this is efficient, but it should work well on a smallish table.

EDIT:

To handle ordering, one approach is to convert to a string:

```
select p.*
from paths p
where not exists (select 1
                  from paths p2
                  where array_to_string(p2.path, ',') like array_to_string(p.path, ',') || ',%' 
                 );
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work...I ran this test query but it fails to bring back any rows 

```with paths(path) AS (VALUES(array[1]), (array[1, 2]),(array[1, 2, 3]))

select p.* from paths p 

where not exists (select 1 from paths p2 where p2.path @> p.path);```

Comment: @jonny . . . Oops.  An array contains itself.  So we need an inequality condition as well.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It's definitely closer, but it looks like the `<@` operator doesn't work in my case because it compares by value rather than by subset. So it matches against (and removes) e.g. `{16, 85, 1}` because `{16, 85, 80, 1}` contains all 3 of the former values...but in my case, order matters.

Comment: Ahhh it looks like the array_to_string requires a delimiter, (you might want to edit your answer) - accepted!